# ASP.NET MVC RAZOR ActionLink click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this action link in view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", null, new {@id="editLink", @class="button"})
```

I would like to call a java script method to make the URI at runtime from my Selected List Box Item.

```
@Html.ListBox("EmployeeName", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.selectlist, new { @id = "saglistbox", @class = "SAGListbox" })
```

As a first step, when i am trying to just display an alert using JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#editLink').click(function () {
        alert("hello");
    });
</script>
```

For some reason this is not working as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were not binding event at when DOM is completely loaded.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#editLink').click(function () {
        alert("hello");

        //To get selected value use
        var selected = $("#EmployeeName").find(':selected').text();

        //To stop default behaviour
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Second `make the URI at runtime from my Selected List Box Item` then you have to stop it default behavior thus used `return false`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#editLink').click(function ()
        {
            alert("hello");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any html attribute as parameter to generate the action link. You can do this as well:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", null, new { @id="editLink", @class="button", onclick = "myfunction()" })
```